# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a dialog box appearing on my page every time I open it. I want to close it so that I can proceed with my programming. 
 The dialogue box is like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7flUy.png)

I tried the following code :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#psyma_layer_background div#psyma_header div#psyma_close_link_container div#psyma_close_link a#psyma_close_button_link")));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#psyma_layer_background div#psyma_header div#psyma_close_link_container div#psyma_close_link a#psyma_close_button_link")));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div#psyma_layer_background div#psyma_header div#psyma_close_link_container div#psyma_close_link a#psyma_close_button_link"))).click();
```

I did presence of element check, visiblity and clickability check so that I do not miss the element by any chance but it's not able to figure out the "X" sign and so not closing the dialogue box! Please help me out if you can, really struggling with this one

Comment: Your css selector is not correct.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying but Im sure this is correct as I tried with the click action in console and id did closed the pop up box. so Im sure its correct :(

Comment: Can you provide html around the close button

Answer (score 0):

It seems you were pretty close. To close the *dialog box appearing on your page* you need to click on the element marked as **X** which is a `<a>` tag. So to invoke `click()` on the desired element you need to wait for the desired *element to be clickable* as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.landrover.co.uk");
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("X"))).click();
  System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Starting ChromeDriver 2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab) on port 15398
  Only local connections are allowed.
  Jun 18, 2018 2:52:08 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
  INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
  Premium 4x4 Vehicles & Luxury SUVs - Land Rover UK
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: landrover]