# Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe, same-origin-policy

I am trying to list the names of all the `iframe`s in a page, so I can access them through Selenium.

The problem is that the name of the `iframe` changes each time, so I need to loop through all of them.

I am getting:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

error when I try to loop over them using:

```
for (var f = 0; f < window.frames.length; f++) {
    console.log(window.frames[f].name)
}
```

Is there a way to get the name of the `iframe` in a different way?

Comment: Maybe [Document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)?

Comment: are you using `javascript` with selenium or another language?

Comment: I'm using `javascript` + selenium

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error message...

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance **blocked** from accessing a cross-origin frame.

---

### Same-origin policy

[**Same-origin policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) : Same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a *critical security mechanism* for isolating potentially malicious documents.

---

### Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

[**Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) : Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional *HTTP headers* to tell a *Browser Client* to let the *AUT (Application under Test)* running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin. A web application makes a *cross-origin HTTP request* when it requests a resource that has a different origin (`domain`, `protocol`, and `port`) than its own origin.

---

### Example of an origin

Here is an example of origin comparisons to the URL **`http://store.company.com/dir/page.html`**

```
URL                                                  Outcome    Reason
http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html             Success
http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html      Success
https://store.company.com/secure.html                Failure    Different protocol
http://store.company.com:81/dir/etc.html             Failure    Different port
http://news.company.com/dir/other.html               Failure    Different host
```

---

### What went wrong

When you tried to loop through `frames` your script/program tried to access an `<iframe>` with different origin using JavaScript which would been a huge *security flaw* if you would have achieved it. As mentioned above the *same-origin policy* browsers block scripts trying to access a `<iframe>` with a different origin.

Two pages have the same origin if the **protocol**, **port** (if one is specified), and **host** are the same for both the webpages. You'll see this referred to as the **`"scheme/host/port tuple"`** at times (where a "tuple" is a set of three components that together comprise a whole). Perhaps the **protocol**, **domain**, **hostname** and **port** must be the same of your same domain when you want to access the desired frame.

### Solution

The *AUT* may contain numerous *frames* / *iframes* and some of them may be loaded only after certain *JavaScript* / *Ajax* have completed where as some of them may be having *style* attribute set as **display:none;** or *visiblity* as **hidden**. Of-course won't require to interact with all of them. So it will be a better approach to identify the *attributes* of the `<iframe>` and switch accordingly. You can switch to an `<iframe>` through:

- `Frame Name`
- `Frame ID`
- `Frame Index`
- `WebElement`

As per *best practices* when you intent to switch to a frame induce [**WebDriverWait**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) for [**frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt-org.openqa.selenium.By-) as per the references below.

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Uncaught DOMException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893169/uncaught-domexception-failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-the-node-to-be/50906407#50906407)

---

### References

Some references:

- In this discussion you will find a detailed analysis on [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)
- In this discussion you will find the different approaches on [Is it possible to switch to an element in a frame without using driver.switchTo().frame(“frameName”) in Selenium Webdriver Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467518/is-it-possible-to-switch-to-an-element-in-a-frame-without-using-driver-switchto/47472200#47472200)
- In the `A Better Approach to Switch Frames` section of this discussion you will find the different approaches on [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770144/how-can-i-select-a-html-element-no-matter-what-frame-it-is-in-in-selenium/47771879#47771879)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `selenium` to get iframe tags like this:

```
var iframeElems = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.xpath("//iframe"));
```

Then loop on those elements and get the ***name*** attribute:

```
iframe.getAttribute('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : (Not sure about JavaScript)

```
var iframeElems = driver.findElements(webdriver.By.tagName("iframe"));
```

iterate this list to get the attribute.

```
for (var f = 0; f < iframeElems.length; f++) {
    console.log(iframeElems.getAttribute("attribute name"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution:

for windows:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="" --disable-web-security
```

for mac:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=""
```

In this way you open the chrome and let it ignore the web security.