# Error: Permission denied to access property "x" due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, perl, same-origin-policy, cross-origin-read-blocking

I want to access to the content of a script which is inside another HTML element which I can Identify easily. I've tried to find the element by getting the parent and then looking for a child but I've not been able to do it.

So I tried to get it just using the console in firefox and use that element to read the content and I'm not able to do it. It looks like this:
[image: example]

When I tried to do anything with that element I get a link to the following page and error:

```
Permission denied to access property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default
```

Is not possible to access to that object for automatic testing with selenium?

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
Permission denied to access property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default
```

...implies that the script/program was attempting to access an object for which you have no permission. This is likely an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element loaded from a different domain for which you violated the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

---

### Same-origin policy

The [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) is a critical security mechanism that restricts how a document or script loaded from one [origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/origin) can interact with a resource from another origin. It helps isolate potentially malicious documents, reducing possible attack vectors.

---

### origin

Two URLs have the same origin if the [protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/protocol), [port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/port) (if specified), and [host](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/host) are the same for both. You may see this referenced as the "scheme/host/port tuple", or just "tuple". (A "tuple" is a set of items that together comprise a whole — a generic form for double/triple/quadruple/quintuple/etc.)

---

### An Example

The following table gives examples of origin comparisons with the URL `http://store.company.com/dir/page.html`:

```
URL                                                  Outcome    Reason
http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html             Success    Only the path differs
http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html      Success    Only the path differs
https://store.company.com/page.html                  Failure    Different protocol
http://store.company.com:81/dir/page.html            Failure    Different port (http:// is port 80 by default)
http://news.company.com/dir/page.html                Failure    Different host
```

> You can also find [origin definition for file: URLs] where the comparison is more complicated.

---

### Inherited origins

Scripts executed from pages with an **`about:blank`** or **`javascript:`** URL inherit the origin of the document containing that URL, since these types of URLs do not contain information about an origin server.

> For example, **`about:blank`** is often used as a URL of new, empty popup windows into which the parent script writes content (e.g. via the `Window.open()` mechanism). If this popup also contains JavaScript, that script would inherit the same origin as the script that created it.
>
> **`data:`**: URLs get a new, empty, security context.

---

### Changing origin

A page may change its own origin, with some limitations. A script can set the value of `document.domain` to its current domain or a superdomain of its current domain. If set to a superdomain of the current domain, the shorter superdomain is used for same-origin checks.

For example, assume a script from the document at `http://store.company.com/dir/other.html` executes the following:

```
document.domain = "company.com";
```

Afterward, the page can pass the same-origin check with `http://company.com/dir/page.html` (assuming `http://company.com/dir/page.html` sets its [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain) to **`company.com`** to indicate that it wishes to allow that). However, `company.com` could **not** set `document.domain` to `othercompany.com`, since that is not a superdomain of `company.com`.

The port number is checked separately by the browser. Any call to `document.domain`, including `document.domain = document.domain`, causes the port number to be overwritten with `null`. Therefore, one cannot make `company.com:8080` talk to `company.com` by only setting `document.domain = "company.com"` in the first. It has to be set in both so their port numbers are both null.

> **Note**: When using `document.domain` to allow a subdomain to access its parent securely, you need to set `document.domain` to the same value in both the parent domain and the subdomain. This is necessary even if doing so is simply setting the parent domain back to its original value. Failure to do this may result in permission errors.

---

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* while switching frames as follows:

- *Java* sample code:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("iframe_id")));
  ```
- *Python* sample code:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe_id")))
  ```

---

### Outro

A couple of related discussions:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478)
- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)