# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "__eventWrappers1573722857587"

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am seeing the error while trying to run the findElement method. I am using the Selenium version 3.141.59 and firefox 45.5.1

```
WebElement weCustomizeDashboardBtn = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[text()='Customize Dashboard']");
```

```
14-11-2019 09:18:52.424 UTC[Thread:11] - org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "__eventWrappers1573722857587"
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.or.oc.net.pages.Dashboard.showOnDashboard(Dashboard.java:47)
```

Comment: What is the geckodriver version?  firefox 45 is quite old.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Permission denied to access property "__eventWrappers1573722857587"
```

...implies that **WebDriverException** was raised while trying to access the property.

---

As per the documentation in [Error: Permission denied to access property "x"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Property_access_denied) this error is observed if your program attempts to access an object for which your program have no permission. These events are likely to occur while accessing an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe/53276478#53276478) element loaded from a different domain for which you violated the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You code trials and the relevant HTML would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However you can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)
- [Error: Permission denied to access property “x” due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)

---

### Additional Considerations

You are using **Firefox v45.5.1** which is pretty ancient. Ideally you need to:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.26.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.25.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.