# XHR request getting blocked and showing HTTP status code 405 with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, cross-domain, webdriverwait

Hi I am new to Selenium based automation. I am trying to load a page in Selenium with Python. But the website is blocking me.

They are sending XHR request to the site and redirecting based on the response. This works properly with manual process, i.e. manually putting in the ZIP code and selecting a pickup location. But when I try the same using Selenium driver its throwing 405 status code.

I went through few searches and they are asking to disable CORS in selenium, but that as well returns the same status code.

Is there any way I can handle CORS in selenium drivers?

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
# options.add_argument("--disable-web-security") <-- tried disabling CORS for selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver", chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.peapod.com/")
enter_zip = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#zipInput--top")
enter_zip.send_keys("60412")
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#guest-form--top > div.gateway-login_input-container > div > label > div.gateway-login_button-container > button")

submit_button.click()  

time.sleep(5)

# selecting the first location slot
location_selection = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".location_select > button")
location_selection.click()  <-- this is the place it is getting blocked and throwing 405 status code
```

Is there any way to get past this or is there any JavaScript running which detects the browser type? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

### 405 Method Not Allowed

As per the documentation the HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) response status code indicates that the request method though is known by the webserver but is not supported by the target resource.

The simplest solution would be to configure the server to generate an **`Allow`** header field in a 405 response containing a list of the target resource's currently supported methods.

I took your own code, added a couple of required *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and  and executed the program and was able to invoke `click()` on the <kbd>Select</kbd> button as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.peapod.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#zipInput--top"))).send_keys("60412")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.gateway-login_button-container button:first-of-type").click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.location_select button.button.button--prime"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: select_location]

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) relevant discussions in:

- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)
- [Error: Permission denied to access property “x” due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)