# Is there way to disable CORS check using RemoteWebDriver for SauceLabs

Tags: java, selenium, automation, saucelabs

Question says it all, I m trying to execute some selenium tests on SauceLabs, the test loads a webpage that makes a cross domain request. I was thinking is there a way to disable CORS, in platform-independent way through code.

Comment: On a server you control? Yes-set the appropriate headers. On a server you don’t control? Trust would defeat the purpose. You could set up a proxy so you’re not making Ajax requests, although you might have to play some games, and it still might not work.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks, the turn-around was rapid. ;)

Comment: Google didnt reveal much about the issue at hand

Comment: Is it a server you control?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While using *ChromeDriver* / *Chrome* combo to disable [cors](/questions/tagged/cors) check you can use the **`--disable-web-security`** argument.

[image: sameoriginpolicy]

which is defined in [content_switches.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc?q=kDisableWebSecurity&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=306) as:

```
// Don't enforce the same-origin policy. (Used by people testing their sites.)
const char kDisableWebSecurity[]            = "disable-web-security";
```

---

Code samples:

- Windows:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); // don't enforce the same-origin policy
  options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
  options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp"); // applicable to windows os only
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  ```
- OSX:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); // don't enforce the same-origin policy
  options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome_dev_test");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  ```
- Linux

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--disable-web-security"); // don't enforce the same-origin policy
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://google.com");
  ```

> **Note**: If you need access to local files for development/testing purposes like AJAX or JSON, you can use **`-–allow-file-access-from-files`** flag.

[image: allowfileaccess]

---

### References

- [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)
- [Disable-web-security in Chrome 48+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432749/disable-web-security-in-chrome-48)
- [Run Chrome browser without CORS](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/)

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)
- [Error: Permission denied to access property “x” due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)

Comment: Thanks, I eventually came to same solution.

Comment: Thank you for adding the reference to my post

Comment: @AlexFilatov Your post was very helpful to explain the subject matter. Thanks for sharing your valuable research.