# WebDriverException: 'SecurityError: The operation is insecure.' error using document.write() within Firefox through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, same-origin-policy

I need to load a page in Firefox selenium and then rewrite the content of the page, It's essential that I use Firefox so Chrome is not an option.

I tried the below code

```
FirefoxDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxOptions() { AcceptInsecureCertificates = true });
            
IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)firefoxDriver;
firefoxDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("document.write('a');");
```

But it gives me the error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

`

I need to know if there is any option in `about:config` or any way to make Firefox run insecure operations.

Answer (score 1):

### Document.write()

The [`Document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) method writes a string of text to a document stream, calling `document.write()` on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls `document.open()`, which will clear the document.

For a long time, [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) and [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) additionally erased all JavaScript variables in addition to removing all nodes. But this is no longer the case. However [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) still continues to do so.

- Equivalent Python code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://google.com")
  driver.execute_script("document.write('a');")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Chrome]

---

### [Gecko-specific notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open#Notes)

> Starting with Gecko 1.9, this method is subject to the same
> [same-origin
> policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)
> as other properties, and does not work if doing so would change the
> document's origin.
>
> Starting with Gecko 1.9.2, `document.open(`) uses the principal of the
> document whose URI it uses, instead of fetching the principal off the
> stack. As a result, you can no longer call `document.write()` into an
> untrusted document from chrome, even using
> [wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/wrappedJSObject).

---

### tl; dr

See [Security check basics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Script_security) for more about principals.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from/51174271#51174271)
- [Is there way to disable CORS check using RemoteWebDriver for SauceLabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59104516/is-there-way-to-disable-cors-check-using-remotewebdriver-for-saucelabs/59111770#59111770)