# SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "pageXOffset" on cross-origin object

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to take a screenshot using Selenium with Python 3.9 but suddenly I've got the error as:

```
Message: SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "pageXOffset" on cross-origin object
```

I've tried to use:

```
profile.setPreference("privacy.trackingprotection.enabled", false)
```

But it does not work. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Security/Tracking Protection

Tracking protection is a technology that helps us to block HTTP loads at the network level based on the [Safe Browsing](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Safe_Browsing) technology which empowers us to fight against against phishing attempts and malwares.

This functionality was a part of the [Polaris](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Polaris) initiative and included some of tracking protection settings:

- *`browser.contentblocking.enabled`*: master switch for all content blocking features (includes tracking protection, but excludes tracking annotations).
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.annotate_channels`*: flag network channels loading resources on the tracking list.
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.enabled`*: to enable [Tracking Protection](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Tracking_protection) globally.
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.lower_network_priority`*: lower the priority of channels loading tracking resources.
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.pbmode.enabled`*: to enable Tracking Protection in Private Browsing mode (not needed if the global pref is enabled)
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.introCount`*
- *`privacy.trackingprotection.introURL`*: URL that kicks off the UI tour (target of the "See how this works" button in about:privatebrowsing).

---

### This usecase

This error message...

```
Message: SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "pageXOffset" on cross-origin object
```

...implies that permission denied when the browsing engine tried to access the property `pageXOffset` due to [cross-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55628911/7429447)

---

### Solution

Lower the security level by removing the tracking protection preferances including:

```
profile.setPreference("privacy.trackingprotection.enabled", false)
```

and execute your test.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51174271/7429447)
- [Is there way to disable CORS check using RemoteWebDriver for SauceLabs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111770/7429447)

Comment: I already said I tried this code, and yours it is for another programming language