# SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object error clicking on download link in iframe using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, same-origin-policy, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am working on an automation project and I am trying to download a pdf from a website. The website only contains the pdf but the file type of the webpage is HTML. The pdf is displayed using PDF.js and the PDF.js viewer is also in an iframe.

When I tried to click the element using browser javascript, i was returned with a security error relating to cross site scripting.

```
SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object
```

I would like to download the pdf from my script, written in python, using selenium. When I try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('download').click()
```

No results are produced, the download button doesn't get clicked even though I have switched focus to the iframe in selenium.

Does anybody know a solution how to download the pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "download"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#download"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='download']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Error: Permission denied to access property “x” due to same/cross origin policy using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55621387/error-permission-denied-to-access-property-x-due-to-same-cross-origin-policy/55628911#55628911)

Comment: I used your code:
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "download"))).click()

However I now receive this error: 'Exception has occurred: ElementClickInterceptedException' How do I get around this?

Comment: @EC Can you update the question with the complete error trace log please?

Comment: @EC `someId`, `someClass`, `someJS`, etc won't help me to improve the answer. The relevant html and the exact error trace log holds the key to a solution.

Comment: Modified question. Do you know how to avoid this error?

Comment: @EC Locator in the question is `find_element_by_id('download')` where as the locator in the error is `(By.ID, "ctl00_PH_AvailableReport1_UCAvailRpt_dgAvailableReport_ctl00_ctl06_lnkRptOpt")`. Do you realize now how essential it is to publish the relevant text based HTML?