# Cross domain communication between SAPUI5 app and iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, sapui5

We are integrating third party maps using iframe in XML view.

The requirement is when user clicks on the map(maps are iframe here), I have to get the coordinates of that location.

I am trying to add click event for that iframe but it is not working.

I tried uisng this code  (http://pbojinov.github.io/iframe-communication/)

Code:

XML view:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
height="100%" controllerName="view.Main">
<Page>
<Label text="Iframe Content"/>
    <Input id="mapValue" type="Text" width="20%"></Input>
  <IconTabBar id="idIconTabBar" upperCase="true" expanded="{device>/isNoPhone}" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
     <items>
        <IconTabFilter text="Search" tooltip="Find Asset/Location">
           <html:iframe name="iFrameMaptest" id="iFrameContent" src="https://XXXX:XXX../" height="100%" width="100%" />
        </IconTabFilter>
     </items>
  </IconTabBar>
```

Controller code:

```
sap.ui.controller("view.Main", {
onInit: function () {
    if (this.getView().byId("iFrameContent")) {
        this.getView().byId("iFrameContent").addEventDelegate({
            "onAfterRendering": function () {
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener("message", this.displayMessage.bind(this), false);
                } else {
                    window.attachEvent("onmessage", this.displayMessage.bind(this));
                }
            }
        }, this);
    }
},

onAfterRendering: function () {
    var oHeight = $(document).height();

    var oInput = this.getView().byId("mapValue");

     var oIframeContent=document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;

    // Listen to messages from parent window
    this.bindEvent(window, 'message', function (e) {
      // oInput.setValue(e.data);
    });
    // Send random message data on every button click
    this.bindEvent(oIframeContent, 'click', function (e) {
        var random = Math.random();
        this.sendMessage(""+ random);

    });

},
displayMessage: function (oEvent) {
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Iframe clciked");
},
bindEvent: function (element, eventName, eventHandler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
    }
},
sendMessage: function (msg) {
    window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
}
```

});

Error:
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://XXX.XXX.." from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: If you have access to the HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage Dont do `contentWindow.callfunction()` stuff. It never works out on the long run.

Comment: How can I resolve the above error ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much a SAPUI5 question, as a general web development question. Check the following posts:

[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

[Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin “http://localhost:8080” from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from)

You could also use a reverse proxy to get around this limitation.