# Angular ng-recpatcha not Resolving

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I am using ng-recpatcha on angular and it was working before, but when I test yesterday I am getting the below error.

```
recaptcha__en.js:690 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at sl.E.AB (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/Q_rrUPkK1sXoHi4wbuDTgcQR/recaptcha__en.js:690:391)
    at Array.<anonymous> (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/Q_rrUPkK1sXoHi4wbuDTgcQR/recaptcha__en.js:80:147)
    at Object.init (https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/Q_rrUPkK1sXoHi4wbuDTgcQR/recaptcha__en.js:697:270)
    at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=en&v=Q_rrUPkK1sXoHi4wbuDTgcQR&k=6LfLHJ8UAAAAAHjEXQCFQc4ZaiTAzFThq85FC2-u&cb=ijqb06acayoo:184:30
```

the Recaptcha is rendering on the screen but when i click on the resolve its not Resolving the captcha. below is my package details file

```
"@angular/core": "^9.1.11",
"ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
"tslint": "^6.1.2",
"typescript": "~3.8.3"
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame while listing the iframes in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51163151/uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-http-localhost8080-from)

Comment: it helped, problem resolved, thanks